# How to read in dataset containing special characters in pandas

Tags: pandas, special-characters, txt

I am trying to read in the following dataset:
https://data.opensanctions.org/datasets/20230620/default/names.txt

I have run this code:

```
filename = "https://data.opensanctions.org/datasets/20230620/default/names.txt"

df = pd.read_csv(filename, encoding='latin1', nrows = 2, header=None)
print(df)
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
                                                   0
0                                SANAVBARI NIKITENKO
1  ÐÐÐÐÐÐ¢ Ð ÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐÐ ÐÐ¥ÐÐÐÐ...
```

How can I automatically detect the special character types when I read in the file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working remove `encoding='latin1'`, so is used default `encoding='utf-8'`:

```
filename = "https://data.opensanctions.org/datasets/20230620/default/names.txt"

df = pd.read_csv(filename, nrows = 2, header=None)
print(df)
                            0
0         SANAVBARI NIKITENKO
1  АМИНАТ РАМЗАНОВНА АХМАДОВА
```